# In Xcode 4.5, why can't I select any file for the right-hand pane from 'Manual' in AssistantEditor?

Tags: xcode, editor

Longtime Xcode 3 user.  New to Xcode 4.5.  When using the new AssistantEditor (Split-pane window) feature of Xcode and I choose 'Manual' as the content, sometimes it lets me navigate down from the root of a project so I can get to any file I want.  However, sometimes 'Manual' only shows me a single file.

For instance, below for the right pane, I can only select MainViewController.h and nothing else in my project, regardless of where the selection is in the Project Navigator or what's open in the left pane.  This is really frustrating that something so basic is not clear.

[image: Can't select other files]

For a pseudo-work-around, I changed my preferences to the following which lets me Option-click a file to open it in the other pane.  A little better, but still frustrating.

[image]

As an aside, I personally find it really frustrating it's not smart enough to know if your focus is in the second (rightmost) pane and you change selection in Project Navigator, change that pane, not the first.  It would be so much easier to reference disparate files side-by-side that way.

### Update: Duh!

Well apparently I'm blind. Turns out you can have it follow the focused editor. (And I was just there too!)

[image]

While this doesn't answer my question of why the 'Manual' item is seemingly broken, this is actually how I prefer to work anyway.  Still, I'll leave this open in case someone figures out that issue.

Comment: I find that when this happens I can resolve it by clicking the back arrow once or more. Real annoying.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too, but there doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to what that's doing.  It's not consistent so I don't rely on that either.  I will say that since I found the 'Optional Navigation' preference, I really don't think I'd use 'Manual' anymore anyway.  Still wish it just tracked focus though.  Regardless, glad I'm not alone here.

Comment: The scary version of this annoyance - it sometimes carries a memory of the last file it had open in the assistant editor, _even if it is from an unrelated project_, and default to opening it. You can easily end up editing the wrong file from the wrong project. And because of the annoyance that triggered this question, you can't simply change it to the file you want. Is there a setting that can disable this behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for the info. As a side note for anyone else. I get the right pane to show the whole tree by pressing cmd+up, which goes to the file's counter part. It does smack some sense into the control though. 

However I prefer this option+click. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can display the assistant editor:

[image: Assistant editor]

and change the mode to `Manual`:

[image: Manual selection]

Then you can quick open a file using `Cmd+Shift+O` and then hit `Enter` to open it on the left editor, or `Alt+Enter` to open it on the right editor.

[image: Quick open]

You can do a similar thing on the project navigator: `click` a file to open it on the left editor, or `Alt+click` to open it on the right editor.

And you can also use tabs:

[image: new tab]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this happens, but it's been present in xCode 5 and xCode 6 at least. Try changing to automatic and then select Manual again. If this doesn't solve your problem after several tries, close xCode and reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to switch to a different file in the right pane by clicking the compiler warnings navigator arrows in the upper right of that pane. Then the "Manual" dropdown showed the entire workspace structure again. Extremely annoying bug in the Xcode interface.

Comment: Ha. Works every time. Glad to finally have this figured out.

Answer (score -2):

From my experience, the right hand side is always the relation to the left side so if I select the .m file on the left side, the .h file will show on your right and vise versa.

Comment: Not always! You can actually navigate to whatever you want there. Having it reflect the related h file or m file is an option, but it's not the only one.